# CheckedListBox and Binding Object Properties to Items

Tags: c#, winforms, reflection, .net-4.0, checkedlistbox

I'm curious if there is a simple way to bind properties of a class to individual items of a CheckedListBox. There are several components out there (Telerik/DevExpress) that provide PropertyEditor grids, but I'm looking to do it in a CheckedListBox.

IE:

```
public class MyItem
{
    public bool Property1
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public bool Property2
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public bool Property3
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

And when adding items to the CheckedListBox, I'd like to have some sort of method that lets me do:

```
this.AddCheckListBoxItem("Property A", this.myItem.Property1);
this.AddCheckListBoxItem("Property B", this.myItem.Property2);
this.AddCheckListBoxItem("Property C", this.myItem.Property3);
```

the first parameter being the display name within the CheckedListBox.

Then throughout any changes to the checkstate, the bool values would automatically be updated without further code.

Comment: I have an Idea of how to do this it's going to take me a few minutes to implement it though, you would need to use reflection i think.

Comment: I know how to do it using reflection, I'd hate to use reflection just for this though. Was trying to think of an alternative way.

Comment: don't think so. Why would you hate to use reflection though?

Comment: On second thought, I wouldn't necessarily hate using reflection for this, though I was hoping there was a way to do it without reflection. Whatever gets it done works for me though.

Comment: True true, just remember if this is going to be used often and the method that calls reflection is called often to cache that call, as reflection is quite an expensive operation.

Comment: @Jethro as it is that there are no other suggested answers, when you get a chance, post an answer for credit.

Comment: thanks. If you need help building this, please let me know as I would also like to perhaps use this Helper class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created a solution using reflection as suggested by @Jethro. I used generics in the class definition, but I didn't implement anything that uses them yet. To summarize, basically using reflection, I've bound a single object and it's boolean properties to individual items within a standard CheckedListBox. It's nice as it doesn't require having to code to set the property values and get them when saving data, as the reflection takes care of this.

I created a Form, and added a CheckedListBox to it, and a button. Here's the code side.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Windows.Forms;

/// <summary>
/// The main form.
/// </summary>
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The checked list box property helper.
    /// </summary>
    private CheckedListBoxPropertyHelper<MyItem> helper;

    /// <summary>
    /// My object to bind to the checked list box.
    /// </summary>
    private MyItem myObjectDataSource;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="Form1"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    public Form1()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        this.myObjectDataSource = new MyItem();
        this.helper = new CheckedListBoxPropertyHelper<MyItem>(this.checkedListBox1, this.myObjectDataSource, true);

        this.helper.AddCheckListBoxItem(new CheckedPropertyItem("Property One", "Property1"));
        this.helper.AddCheckListBoxItem(new CheckedPropertyItem("Property Two", "Property2"));
        this.helper.AddCheckListBoxItem(new CheckedPropertyItem("Property Three", "Property3"));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Handles the Click event of the Button1 control.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">The source of the event.</param>
    /// <param name="e">The <see cref="System.EventArgs"/> instance containing the event data.</param>
    private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // In the constructor
        // if we instantiated: this.helper = new CheckedListBoxPropertyHelper<MyItem>(this.checkedListBox1, this.myObjectDataSource, true);
        // as: this.helper = new CheckedListBoxPropertyHelper<MyItem>(this.checkedListBox1, this.myObjectDataSource, false);
        // changing the last bindImmediate property to false, the changes to the checkboxes wouldn't take effect immediately
        // on the underlying object, you need to call this.helper.CommitChanges() at which point the changes
        // will be made to the datasource object.

        // this.helper.CommitChanges();

        Console.WriteLine(this.myObjectDataSource.Property1.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(this.myObjectDataSource.Property2.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(this.myObjectDataSource.Property3.ToString());
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// My item.
/// </summary>
public class MyItem
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a value indicating whether this <see cref="MyItem"/> is property1.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value><c>true</c> if property1; otherwise, <c>false</c>.</value>
    public bool Property1
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a value indicating whether this <see cref="MyItem"/> is property2.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value><c>true</c> if property2; otherwise, <c>false</c>.</value>
    public bool Property2
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a value indicating whether this <see cref="MyItem"/> is property3.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value><c>true</c> if property3; otherwise, <c>false</c>.</value>
    public bool Property3
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// The checked list box property helper. This binds datasource properties to checkedlistbox items.
/// </summary>
public class CheckedListBoxPropertyHelper<T> where T : class
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The checked list box.
    /// </summary>
    private CheckedListBox checkedListBox;

    /// <summary>
    /// The property info.
    /// </summary>
    private PropertyInfo[] PropertyInfo;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="CheckedListBoxPropertyHelper"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="checkedListBox">The checked list box.</param>
    /// <param name="dataSource">The data source.</param>
    /// <param name="bindImmediate">if set to <c>true</c> [bind immediate].</param>
    public CheckedListBoxPropertyHelper(CheckedListBox checkedListBox, T dataSource, bool bindImmediate)
    {
        this.checkedListBox = checkedListBox;
        this.DataSource = dataSource;
        this.PropertyInfo = this.DataSource.GetType().GetProperties();
        this.BindImmediate = bindImmediate;
        this.checkedListBox.ItemCheck += new ItemCheckEventHandler(CheckedListBox_ItemCheck);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The data source.
    /// </summary>
    public T DataSource
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a value indicating whether to [bind immediately] to the datasource object.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value><c>true</c> if [bind immediately]; otherwise, <c>false</c>.</value>
    public bool BindImmediate
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Commits the changes.
    /// </summary>
    public void CommitChanges()
    {
        if (!this.BindImmediate)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < this.checkedListBox.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                CheckedPropertyItem checkedItem = this.checkedListBox.Items[i] as CheckedPropertyItem;
                this.SetChecked(this.checkedListBox.GetItemChecked(i), checkedItem);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("You cannot commit changes when bind immediate is on.");
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Adds the check list box item.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="item">The item.</param>
    public void AddCheckListBoxItem(CheckedPropertyItem item)
    {
        PropertyInfo info = this.GetPropertyInfo(item.PropertyName);
        bool isChecked = false;

        if (info != null)
        {
            isChecked = (bool)info.GetValue(this.DataSource, null);
        }

        this.checkedListBox.Items.Add(item, isChecked);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Handles the ItemCheck event of the CheckedListBox control.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">The source of the event.</param>
    /// <param name="e">The <see cref="System.Windows.Forms.ItemCheckEventArgs"/> instance containing the event data.</param>
    private void CheckedListBox_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
    {
        if (BindImmediate)
        {
            CheckedListBox clb = sender as CheckedListBox;
            CheckedPropertyItem checkedItem = clb.Items[e.Index] as CheckedPropertyItem;

            this.SetChecked(
                e.NewValue == CheckState.Checked ? true : false,
                 checkedItem);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the checked.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="isChecked">if set to <c>true</c> [is checked].</param>
    /// <param name="clb">The CLB.</param>
    private void SetChecked(bool isChecked, CheckedPropertyItem item)
    {
        PropertyInfo info = this.GetPropertyInfo(item.PropertyName);

        if (info.CanWrite)
        {
            info.SetValue(this.DataSource, isChecked, null);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the property info.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="propertyName">Name of the property.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private PropertyInfo GetPropertyInfo(string propertyName)
    {
        return this.PropertyInfo
            .Where(c => c.Name == propertyName)
            .SingleOrDefault();
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Checked Property Item binding.
/// </summary>
public class CheckedPropertyItem
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="CheckedPropertyItem"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="title">The title.</param>
    /// <param name="propertyName">Name of the property.</param>
    public CheckedPropertyItem(string title, string propertyName)
    {
        this.Title = title;
        this.PropertyName = propertyName;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the title.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The title.</value>
    public string Title
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the name of the property.
    /// </summary>
    public string PropertyName
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns a <see cref="System.String"/> that represents this instance.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>A <see cref="System.String"/> that represents this instance.</returns>
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.Title;
    }
}
```

Comment: looks good. Congrats dude. Only one not really important small change I would make. Cache the PropertyInfo of GetPropertyInfo method. Apart from that awesome work!!

Comment: I updated it. I'm getting the PropertyInfo[] for the datasource object within the constructor and storing it.

Comment: I've added a BindImmediate property to the helper. If it is set to false in the constructor, you need to call CommitChanges() for the check state changes to be applied to the underlying datasource. If it is set to true, the changes are reflected immediately after changing the check state.

Answer (score 1):

Currently there isn't any easy/simple way to get the functionallity you are looking for. 
As in the comments the nearest solution I can think of would be to use reflection.

If you manage to build a helper class that has this functionallity, please post here as I would also find that usefull.

Comment: I've posted code that performs this functionality. Have a look and let me know what you think. There's several parts that can be enhanced, but this is the general idea I think.